# Pulling multiple, non-consecutive index values from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a pandas dataframe reading it from a scipy.io in the following way (file.sav is an IDL structure created on a different machine. The scipy.io creates a standard python dictionary):

```
from scipy import io
import pandas as p
import numpy as np
tmp=io.readsav('file.sav', python_dict = True)
df=pd.DataFrame(tmp,index=tmp['shots'].astype('int32'))
```

the dataframe contains a set of values (from file.sav) and as indices a series of integers of the form 19999,20000,30000 etc.
Now I would like to take a subset of these indices, says

```
df.loc[[19999,20000]]
```

for some reasons I get errors of the form

```
raise ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')
```

plus other and at the end

```
ValueError: Big-endian buffer not supported on little-endian compiler
```

But I've checked that both the machine I'm working on and the machine which has created the file.sav are both little endian. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Can you post file.sav somewhere where we can try it? Or, better yet, a small section of file.sav that reproduces the error?

Comment: does `df.loc[19999:20001]` work? do you really have a multi-index (meaning an index comprised of several columns)?

Comment: I made a dummy file.sav available here http://db.tt/lKu7Jcsg. You can try on your self. Now shots is between 20000 and 20099. Actually the system suggested by Paul H works but the problem is that I would like to use indices which are not consecutive. Maybe the name of the question is incorrect. Actually I would like to take a subset of rows of the dataframe

Comment: Can itemgetter work for this? Surely there is a simple way without using a lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input file is big endian. see here to transform it: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#byte-ordering-issues

Compare before and after

```
In [7]: df.dtypes
Out[7]: 
a        >f4
b        >f4
c        >f4
shots    >f4
dtype: object

In [9]: df.apply(lambda x: x.values.byteswap().newbyteorder())
Out[9]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 20000 to 20099
Data columns (total 4 columns):
a        100  non-null values
b        100  non-null values
c        100  non-null values
shots    100  non-null values
dtypes: float32(4)

In [10]: df.apply(lambda x: x.values.byteswap().newbyteorder()).dtypes
Out[10]: 
a        float32
b        float32
c        float32
shots    float32
dtype: object
```

Also set the index AFTER you do this (e.g. don't do it in the constructor)

```
df.set_index('shots',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Actually you are right. I have checked the type of endian on both the machines as sys.byteorder with the same answer as little. So I thought this was not the problem. Actually do you have an idea of the more pythonic way to convert the tmp (which is a python dictionary) to little endian?

Comment: you can what I do in the apply, its operating on the numpy arrays directly. I don't think readsav can do this conversion.

Comment: Ok I found a way. Actually it was a little tricky (at least for me) to preserve the fact that tmp is a dictionary. But I found a workaround (maybe not the best one). Thanks a lot

Comment: ok...you can do the conversion after its a frame in any event (and we may introduce a method to do this directly in 0.13))

Comment: If the Dataframe contain non-numeric data types, you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34530065/1461850).

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, I would approach the problem in the following way:

```
values_i_want = [19999, 20000, 20005, 20007]
subset = df.select(lambda x: x[0] in values_i_want)
```

if your dataframe is very large (sounds like it is), the `select` method will probably be pretty slow. In that case, another approach would be to loop through `values_i_want` taking cross sections (`df.xs(val, level=0`) and appending them to an output dataframe. In other words (untested):

```
for n, val in enumerate(values_i_want):
    if n == 0:
         subset = df.xs(val, level=0)
    else:
         subset = subset.append(df.xs(val, level=0))
```

Not sure if that'll be any faster. But it's worth trying if the `select` approach is too slow.

Comment: Seems the `select` method is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html).