# How do I find numeric columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, types, pandas

Let's say `df` is a pandas DataFrame.
I would like to find all columns of numeric type.
Something like:

```
isNumeric = is_numeric(df)
```

Comment: You should specify whether a column that has `dtype` being `object`, but all elements being numeric, counts as numeric or not. If no, take Hanan's answer, as it is also faster. Otherwise, take mine.

Comment: What happens if you simply try df.describe().columns. Then assign it to a variable.

Comment: Related: [Get list of pandas dataframe columns based on data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470690/get-list-of-pandas-dataframe-columns-based-on-data-type). Then you just need to list the integer and float types to `df.select_dtypes(include=[...])`.

Answer (score 293):

You could use `select_dtypes` method of DataFrame. It includes two parameters include and exclude. So isNumeric would look like:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']

newdf = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
```

As of [Pandas 1.0 you can also just do](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.select_dtypes(include='number')
```

Comment: You could use df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) if you don't need to specify a 'numerics' list

Comment: Building on the tip in the previous comment (+1), you could just use 
`list(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.values)` 
to get a list of names of the numeric columns

Comment: Conversely, a classical filter with string matching is even more performant (measured): `list(filter(lambda x: 'float' not in str(df.dtypes[x]) and 'int' not in str(df.dtypes[x]),  df.columns))`

Comment: One-liner if you want column names `list(df.select_dtypes('number'))` (from pandas v1.0.0)

Comment: This answer looks obsolete. In 2022, "To select all numeric types, use `np.number` or `'number'`", from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Comment: This did not work for me. I was losing the int64 columns. The solution that worked was df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

Answer (score 178):

Simple one-line answer to create a new dataframe with only numeric columns:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```

If you want the names of numeric columns:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(7, 10),
                   'B': np.random.rand(3),
                   'C': ['foo','bar','baz'],
                   'D': ['who','what','when']})
df
#    A         B    C     D
# 0  7  0.704021  foo   who
# 1  8  0.264025  bar  what
# 2  9  0.230671  baz  when

df_numerics_only = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
df_numerics_only
#    A         B
# 0  7  0.704021
# 1  8  0.264025
# 2  9  0.230671

colnames_numerics_only = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns.tolist()
colnames_numerics_only
# ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: `df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.tolist()`

Comment: If you only want one type, you don't need to store it in a list. Nor do you need to specify `include=`. `select_dtypes(np.number)`

Comment: If your columns have numeric data but also have None, the dtype could be 'object'. This will coerce the columns to numeric: `df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: also: `df.select_dtypes('number')`. It's even shorter and you don't have to import numpy

Answer (score 93):

You can use the undocumented function `_get_numeric_data()` to filter only numeric columns:

```
df._get_numeric_data()
```

Example:

```
In [32]: data
Out[32]:
   A  B
0  1  s
1  2  s
2  3  s
3  4  s

In [33]: data._get_numeric_data()
Out[33]:
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

Note that this is a "private method" (i.e., an implementation detail) and is subject to change or total removal in the future. **Use with caution**.

Comment: Super handy; is this documented anywhere? Concerned about it disappearing in future versions and/or instability, as [its prefix underscore indicates that it's meant to be private.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/588437)

Comment: No, this isn't documented anywhere. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/870b6a6d6415c76d051b287adcb180ac3020b6e8/pandas/core/generic.py#L3538-L3540), however, like @ijoseph mentioned I would be wary of using methods that begin with underscores as they are little more than implementation details. Use literally ANY other answer besides this.

Comment: Exactly. As a best practice I try to use and convert to as many numpy methods as possible. This is due to pandas dynamism. The API changes frequently. For undocumented methods it's just plain reckless, no matter how useful it is.

Answer (score 76):

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude = ['object'])
```

**Update:**

```
df.select_dtypes(include= np.number)
```

or with new version of panda

```
 df.select_dtypes('number')
```

Comment: datetime columns are a different type `datetime` thay are not numeric types

Comment: I really liked the above: `df.select_dtypes(include= np.number)` for numeric columns and for non numeric cols: `df.select_dtypes(exclude= np.number)` ... it is helpful to me..

Comment: In my case I also needed to exclude timedeltas: select_dtypes(include='number', exclude='timedelta').  Perhaps this is obvious to others!  Leaving here just in case it is not!

Answer (score 46):

Simple one-liner:

```
df.select_dtypes('number').columns
```

Comment: By far the most Pythonic way, yes.

Answer (score 10):

Following codes will return list of names of the numeric columns of a data set.

```
cnames=list(marketing_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns)
```

here `marketing_train` is my data set and `select_dtypes()` is function to select data types using exclude and include arguments and columns is used to fetch the column name of data set
output of above code will be following:

```
['custAge',
     'campaign',
     'pdays',
     'previous',
     'emp.var.rate',
     'cons.price.idx',
     'cons.conf.idx',
     'euribor3m',
     'nr.employed',
     'pmonths',
     'pastEmail']
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another simple code for finding numeric column in pandas data frame,

```
numeric_clmns = df.dtypes[df.dtypes != "object"].index
```

Answer (score 4):

We can include and exclude data types as per the requirement as below:

```
train.select_dtypes(include=None, exclude=None)
train.select_dtypes(include='number') #will include all the numeric types
```

Referred from Jupyter Notebook.

To select all *numeric* types, use `np.number` or `'number'`

- To select strings you must use the `object` dtype but note that
  this will return *all* object dtype columns
- See the `NumPy dtype hierarchy <http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html>`__
- To select datetimes, use `np.datetime64`, `'datetime'` or
  `'datetime64'`
- To select timedeltas, use `np.timedelta64`, `'timedelta'` or
  `'timedelta64'`
- To select Pandas categorical dtypes, use `'category'`
- To select Pandas datetimetz dtypes, use `'datetimetz'` (new in
  0.20.0) or ``'datetime64[ns, tz]'

Answer (score 4):

Although this is old subject,

but i think the following formula is easier than all other comments

`df[df.describe().columns]`

As the function describe() only works for numeric columns, the column of the output will only be numeric.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm this works, so thanks for that, but I also would love an explanation of WHY it works.  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: @Adam As the function `describe()` only works for numeric columns, so the column of the output will only be numeric

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code:

```
if(dataset.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).shape[1] > 0):
display(dataset.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).describe())
if(dataset.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).shape[1] > 0):
display(dataset.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).describe())
```

This way you can check whether the value are numeric such as float and int or the srting values. the second if statement is used for checking the string values which is referred by the object.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the posted answers are inefficient. These answers either return/select a subset of the original dataframe (a needless copy) or  perform needless computational statistics in the case of `describe()`.

To just get the column names that are numeric, one can use a conditional list comprehension with the [pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html) function:

```
numeric_cols = [col for col in df if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[col])]
```

I'm not sure when this function was introduced.

Comment: Best answer so far! Note that this also selects "bool" as a numeric dtype! If you're looking for "real numbers only" then `pd.api.types.is_any_real_numeric_dtype()` does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

@Kathiramani Sukumar's answer `df._get_numeric_data()` takes the cake.

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'Numeric':[20,10,np.nan],'String':['foo','bar','daa'],'Date':[datetime(2023,1,1,0,0,0),datetime(2023,1,2,0,0,0),np.nan]})
xdf.dtypes
Numeric           float64
String             object
Date       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

%timeit xdf._get_numeric_data()
34.7 µs ± 870 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit xdf.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
797 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
%timeit xdf.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
991 µs ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21772078/2223706), you could do

```
df.ix[:,df.applymap(np.isreal).all(axis=0)]
```

Here, `np.applymap(np.isreal)` shows whether every cell in the data frame is numeric, and `.axis(all=0)` checks if all values in a column are True and returns a series of Booleans that can be used to index the desired columns.

Answer (score 0):

`numerical_col = df.describe().columns.to_list()`

This is what i normally use.
Since the describe method only returns numerical columns.

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_type(df, baseType):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    test = [issubclass(np.dtype(d).type, baseType) for d in df.dtypes]
    return pd.DataFrame(data = test, index = df.columns, columns = ["test"])
def is_float(df):
    import numpy as np
    return is_type(df, np.float)
def is_number(df):
    import numpy as np
    return is_type(df, np.number)
def is_integer(df):
    import numpy as np
    return is_type(df, np.integer)
```