# Get all columns with datetime type using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge DataFrame where the columns aren't ever in order nor do I know their name.

What do I do to find all the columns which are datetime types?

Most of the solutions online, the poster knows the name of the column so I am having a bit trouble as I do not. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: What _else_ do the columns have? Other types? `NaN`? Can you add some sample data please?

Comment: I have over 100 columns, some columns are only ints, some are boolean, some are alphanumerical. The datetime column does not have NaN. (There are only 2 of them, I just want to get anyone of them). Let's assume no NaN's. I didn't find any in sample of over 10 datasets.

Comment: related if using numerical columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039626/how-do-i-find-numeric-columns-in-pandas#28155580

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), and include only the datetime64 type.

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64'])
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df
         dts1       dts2  ints
0  2012-01-01 2004-01-01     0
1  2012-01-02 2004-01-02     1
2  2012-01-03 2004-01-03     2
..        ...        ...   ...
97 2012-04-07 2004-04-07    97
98 2012-04-08 2004-04-08    98
99 2012-04-09 2004-04-09    99

>>> df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64'])
         dts1       dts2
0  2012-01-01 2004-01-01
1  2012-01-02 2004-01-02
2  2012-01-03 2004-01-03
..        ...        ...
97 2012-04-07 2004-04-07
98 2012-04-08 2004-04-08
99 2012-04-09 2004-04-09
```

Answer (score 6):

Since each column of a pandas DataFrame is a pandas Series simply iterate through list of column names and conditionally check for `series.dtype` of datetime (typically *datetime64[ns]*):

```
for col in df.columns:
   if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
      print(col)
```

Or as list comprehension:

```
[col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
```

Or as a series filter:

```
df.dtypes[df.dtypes=='datetime64[ns]']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting up this answer for two reasons:

1. It works
2. I want someone to improve it.. there should be some sort of 'all_datetime_types' thingy in Pandas.. and I'm probably just missing it...

```
datetime_types = ["datetime", "datetime64", "datetime64[ns]", "datetimetz"]
for c in df.select_dtypes(include=datetime_types).columns:
    print(f"Doing something with column {c}...")
```

Answer (score 1):

For datetime columns that include datetimes with timezones (e.g. `datetime64[ns, UTC]`), this is a general solution:

```
def get_datetime_columns_of_data_frame(df):
    # dtypes as data frame
    df_type = df.dtypes.rename_axis('column')\
        .to_frame('dtype')\
        .reset_index(drop=False)
    # dtype as string for easier filtering
    df_type['dtype_str'] = df_type['dtype'].map(str)
    return df_type[df_type['dtype_str'].str.contains('datetime64')]['column'].tolist()
```

Comment: `data_frame_dtypes()` function definition is missing in this answer. Please share for completeness of your answer.

Comment: @abhiieor Thanks for spotting it! Added the missing definition.

Comment: @abhiieor Simplified even further into a single function (which was my aim originally, but left the function call in there accidentally).