# Getting columns with datetime format such as (2017-02-12 10:23:55 AM)[YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM] using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I recently asked a question about identifing all the columns which are `datetime`. Here it is: [Get all columns with datetime type using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322950/get-all-columns-with-datetime-type-using-pandas)

The answer was correct for a proper date time format, however, I now realize my data isn't proper date time, it is a string formatted like `"2017-02-12 10:23:55 AM"` and I was advised to create a new question.

I have a huge dataframe with an unknown number of date time columns, where I do not know their names nor their position. How do I identify the column names of the date time columns which have the date of format such as YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM?

Comment: So the dates are actually strings?

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought they were proper dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to test for successful conversion:

```
def is_datetime(datetime_string):
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(datetime_string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

With this:

```
dt_columns = [c for c in df.columns if is_datetime(df[c][0])]
```

> Note:  This tests for any string that can be converted to a `datetime`.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was trying to avoid for loops incase there was a build-in function. But thanks!