# Get all columns in a pandas dataframe that is a date-column when different time-zones are present in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp-with-timezone

(Note, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322950/get-all-columns-with-datetime-type-using-pandas) SO question does not take into account the different time-zones i.e it does not catch a date when a time-zone is present).

I have a dataframe where some column dtypes are `datetime64[ns]` and some are `datetime64[ns,UTC]`.

Note, they have all been converted using

`df["some_time_col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["some_time_col"])` but since `df` is a merge of data across different databases, the time-zones are different.

Is there a way to get all columns that are a date-column i.e something like this

```py
dt_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[pd.datetime]).columns
```

instead of having to specify *all* time-zones like

```py
dt_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=["datetim64","datetime64[UTC]","datetime64[UTC+1]"...).columns
```

Using either of

```
dt_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64]).columns
dt_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=["datetime64"]).columns
```

does not catch `datetime64[ns,UTC]` but only `datetime64[ns]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.select_dtypes('datetimetz')
```

From [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) docs:

> To select Pandas datetimetz dtypes, use 'datetimetz' (new in 0.20.0) or 'datetime64[ns, tz]'

For selecting both `datetime` without tz and with tz, do:

```
df.select_dtypes(['datetimetz', 'np.datetime64'])
```

Comment: how did I miss that ... Although it does ignore the `datetime64[ns]` it seems like i.e it only takes columns that have a time-zone thus I need to do `df.select_dtypes(["datetime64","datetimetz"]).columns`. Isn't there a "meta" datetime object that captures *all* date-columns?

Comment: Seems like there's no superset kinda function that catches both datetime with and without tz cols.

Comment: I cannot find it either - so I think we have to include both