# Selecting all numerical values in data-frame and converting it to int in panda

Tags: python, pandas, types, integer

I have data like:

[image]

I want to make all numerical values to int, no decimal will be here. 
like this:

[image]

I was using code like list:

```
             df=pd.read_csv("file.csv")

             df = df.astype('int64')
```

But it was not working. Because it was saying:

```
          ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

Because, I have some nan value inside. There are string also in the column one row 2&3.
I think the solution could be, selecting all numerical values from the data frame and converting to int. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: the redirected duplicate question seems to be different from this. Here, the problem is not `nan` fill value, but selecting the numerical columns.

Comment: Please do not post code or data in images

Answer (score -1):

There are some null values in your data frame. First, you need to covert them to an integer (for e.g. 0 here). use `df.fillna` for that.
Then select all numerical columns.

```
cols = ["num_col1", "num_col2"]
df[cols] = df[cols].astype("int64")
```

Comment: Where does it say 0 is NA?

Comment: Not a great answer to an especially poor question.

Comment: Wait, am I the only one to understand OPs question? It has also been marked as wrong duplicate. Its more close (not exactly) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039626/how-do-i-find-numeric-columns-in-pandas).