# Select numerical columns of Julia DataFrame with missing values

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to select all columns of a DataFrame in which the datatype is a subtype of `Number`. However, since there are columns with `missing` values, the numerical column datatypes can be something like `Union{Missing, Int64}`.

So far, I came up with:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame([["a", "b"], [1, missing] ,[2, 5]])

df_numerical = df[typeintersect.(colwise(eltype, df), Number) .!= Union{}]
```

This yields the expected result.

**Question**

Is there a more simple, idiomatic way of doing this? Possibly simliar to:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

in pandas as taken from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039626/how-do-i-find-numeric-columns-in-pandas)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> df[(<:).(eltypes(df),Union{Number,Missing})]
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x2      │ x3 │
├─────┼─────────┼────┤
│ 1   │ 1       │ 2  │
│ 2   │ missing │ 5  │
```

Please note that the `.` is the broadcasting operator and hence I had to use `<:` operator in a functional form.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but will fail e.g. for `[missing, missing]` and the type of this vector does not allow numbers.

Comment: I assumed that you do not have normally in a data frame columns that contain nothing else than `missing` values. However if you do you can filer them out: `df[(<:).(eltypes(df),Union{Number,Missing}).&(eltypes(df).!=Missing)]`

Answer (score 3):

An other way to do it could be:

```
df_numerical = df[[i for i in names(df) if Base.nonmissingtype(eltype(df[i])) <: Number]]
```

To retrieve all the columns that are subtype of Number, irrelevantly if they host missing data or not.