# How to get only numeric type columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get only numeric type columns from dataframe.
Can anyone please suggest any solution for this?

Ex:

```
A    B    C
17   398  file
23   476  name
```

O/p:

```
A    B
17   398
23   476
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'float_col': [1.0],
                   'int_col': [1],
                   'datetime_col': [pd.Timestamp('20180310')],
                   'string_col': ['foo']})
df_int = df[df.columns[df.dtypes == np.int64]]
```

In this case, df is the data frame

```
   float_col  int_col datetime_col string_col
0        1.0        1   2018-03-10        foo
```

and df_int is the data frame

```
   int_col
0        1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want to get all numeric type columns from dataframe. I have edited my que can you please suggest solution?

Comment: @Shital See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039626/how-do-i-find-numeric-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Pandas DataFrame has [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method that allows you to select the columns based on the data type.

```py
>>> df.select_dtypes(int)
    A    B
0  17  398
1  23  476
```

You can also pass a sequence for multiple data types for e.g.: `df.select_dtypes((int, float))` which selects all integer, and float value columns.

There are other ways as well around it like converting to numeric then discarding all-NaN columns, but this seems to be the best solution for the data you've mentioned

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want to get all numeric type columns from dataframe. I have edited my que can you please suggest solution?

Comment: Hi @Shital the provided solution works for the new data as well.