# How do I remove columns with non numerical values from a pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to remove all columns whose values are not numbers.

I tried to look at the CSV and type the names of the columns I wanted to be removed. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Could you provide example code and explain what have you tried ?

Comment: This might be helpful for you (tip: use 'exclude' arg instead of 'include'): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28155580/19533532

Answer (score 0):

First, load your CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame, and then filter the columns based on their data types. Here's a code snippet to demonstrate this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Load your CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

# Select only numeric columns
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

# Save the result to a new CSV file
numeric_columns.to_csv("filtered_file.csv", index=False)
```

The `select_dtypes` function is used to select only columns with numeric data types. The resulting DataFrame with only numeric columns is then saved to a new CSV file.